# Scrapy extract text between two selectors of h2 tags

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to extract text from this [webpage](https://www.drugs.com/cg/abdominal-pain-aftercare-instructions.html). The basic idea is to make h2 tag as a key and all the text under that specific h2 tag as a value. What I tried to do is :

```
for cnt, h2 in enumerate(response.xpath('//h2'), start=1):
    print h2.xpath('./following-sibling::node()[count(preceding-sibling::h2)=%d]/descendant-or-self::text()' % cnt).getall()
```

but this is producing lists containing text which I think will require nested for loops and hence I tried this code:

```
h2 = response.xpath('//h2//text()').getall()
p={}
for cnt, h3 in enumerate(response.xpath('//h2'), start=1):
 text=''
 for t in h3.xpath('./following-sibling::node()[count(preceding-sibling::h2)=%d]//text()' % cnt).getall():
    if t in h2:
        p[t] = text
        text=''
    else:
        text=text+t
```

It is somehow producing some results but not acceptable ones.

**Update:**

Expected output would be like:

```
{'Contact your healthcare provider if:': 'You have pain in your lower back.You are a man and have pain in your testicles.You have pain when you urinate.You have questions or concerns about your condition or care.',
 'Follow up with your healthcare provider within 24 hours or as directed:': 'Write down your questions so you remember to ask them during your visits.',
 'Further information': 'Always consult your healthcare provider to ensure the information displayed on this page applies to your personal circumstances.',
 'Medicines:': '\xc2\xa9 Copyright IBM Corporation 2020 Information is for End Users use only and may not be sold, redistributed or otherwise used for commercial purposes. All illustrations and images included in CareNotes\xc2\xae are the copyrighted property of A.D.A.M., Inc. or IBM Watson Health.Medicines may be given to calm your stomach and prevent vomiting or to decrease pain. Ask how to take pain medicine safely.Take your medicine as directed. Contact your healthcare provider if you think your medicine is not helping or if you have side effects. Tell him of her if you are allergic to any medicine. Keep a list of the medicines, vitamins, and herbs you take. Include the amounts, and when and why you take them. Bring the list or the pill bottles to follow-up visits. Carry your medicine list with you in case of an emergency.The above information is an educational aid only. It is not intended as medical advice for individual conditions or treatments. Talk to your doctor, nurse or pharmacist before following any medical regimen to see if it is safe and effective for you.',
 'Return to the emergency department if:': 'You have new chest pain or shortness of breath.You have pulsing pain in your upper abdomen or lower back that suddenly becomes constant.Your pain is in the right lower abdominal area and worsens with movement.You have a fever over 100.4\xc2\xb0F (38\xc2\xb0C) or shaking chills.You are vomiting and cannot keep food or liquids down.Your pain does not improve or gets worse over the next 8 to 12 hours.You see blood in your vomit or bowel movements, or they look black and tarry.Your skin or the whites of your eyes turn yellow.You are a woman and have a large amount of vaginal bleeding that is not your monthly period.',
 'WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW:': 'Abdominal pain can be dull, achy, or sharp. You may have pain in one area of your abdomen, or in your entire abdomen. Your pain may be caused by a condition such as constipation, food sensitivity or poisoning, infection, or a blockage. Abdominal pain can also be from a hernia, appendicitis, or an ulcer. Liver, gallbladder, or kidney conditions can also cause abdominal pain. The cause of your abdominal pain may be unknown.'}
```

Comment: Can you use BeautifulSoup for the task?

Comment: @AndrejKesely will you please show me that how's it possible with beautifulsoup?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example to extract `<h2>`s and their values to dictionary:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.drugs.com/cg/abdominal-pain-aftercare-instructions.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# extract Ads that mess with the article:
for ad in soup.select('.contentAd'):
    ad.extract()

out = {}
for tag in soup.select('#content h2 + *:not(h2), #moreResources'):
    if tag.get('id', '') == 'moreResources':
        break # we don't want anything after this tag
    out[tag.find_previous('h2').text] = tag.get_text(strip=True)

# pretty print the output to screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=120)
```

Prints:

```
{'Contact your healthcare provider if:': 'You have pain in your lower back.You are a man and have pain in your '
                                         'testicles.You have pain when you urinate.You have questions or concerns '
                                         'about your condition or care.',
 'Follow up with your healthcare provider within 24 hours or as directed:': 'Write down your questions so you remember '
                                                                            'to ask them during your visits.',
 'Further information': 'Always consult your healthcare provider to ensure the information displayed on this page '
                        'applies to your personal circumstances.',
 'Medicines:': 'Medicinesmay be given to calm your stomach and prevent vomiting or to decrease pain. Ask how to take '
               'pain medicine safely.Take your medicine as directed.Contact your healthcare provider if you think your '
               'medicine is not helping or if you have side effects. Tell him of her if you are allergic to any '
               'medicine. Keep a list of the medicines, vitamins, and herbs you take. Include the amounts, and when '
               'and why you take them. Bring the list or the pill bottles to follow-up visits. Carry your medicine '
               'list with you in case of an emergency.',
 'Return to the emergency department if:': 'You have new chest pain or shortness of breath.You have pulsing pain in '
                                           'your upper abdomen or lower back that suddenly becomes constant.Your pain '
                                           'is in the right lower abdominal area and worsens with movement.You have a '
                                           'fever over 100.4°F (38°C) or shaking chills.You are vomiting and cannot '
                                           'keep food or liquids down.Your pain does not improve or gets worse over '
                                           'the next 8 to 12 hours.You see blood in your vomit or bowel movements, or '
                                           'they look black and tarry.Your skin or the whites of your eyes turn '
                                           'yellow.You are a woman and have a large amount of vaginal bleeding that is '
                                           'not your monthly period.',
 'WHAT YOU NEED TO KNOW:': 'Abdominal pain can be dull, achy, or sharp. You may have pain in one area of your abdomen, '
                           'or in your entire abdomen. Your pain may be caused by a condition such as constipation, '
                           'food sensitivity or poisoning, infection, or a blockage. Abdominal pain can also be from a '
                           'hernia, appendicitis, or an ulcer. Liver, gallbladder, or kidney conditions can also cause '
                           'abdominal pain. The cause of your abdominal pain may be unknown.'}
```

---

EDIT: New version:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.drugs.com/mcd/asthma-attack'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# extract Ads that mess with the article:
for ad in soup.select('.contentAd'):
    ad.extract()

out = {}
tag = soup.select_one('h2')
current_header = tag.text
while True:
    tag = tag.find_next_sibling()
    if not tag:
        break
    if tag.get('id', '') == 'moreResources':
        break # we don't want anything after this tag
    if tag.name == 'h2':
        current_header = tag.text
    else:
        out.setdefault(current_header, '')
        out[current_header] += tag.get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: thank you very much for putting an effort. I just checked that this solution works well with the given webpage only. If you notice this [link](https://www.drugs.com/mcd/asthma-attack), it's not producing as an expected out.

Comment: @TaimorrMughal I edited my answer, you can try the new version.